# Visual Studio 2010 resource tree doesn't open

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I'm having a problem with visual studio 2010 in that I have a MFC project I've made which includes a dialog box. However when I go to the resource view, I can see the .rc file (I can't see the .rc2 file, which is listed in the solution explorer) but when I click on it, it doesn't open into the expected ICON, DIALOG, MENU etc.

The project runs and compiles fine, but I just don't get why I can't get to the dialog to edit it.
Thanks
James

Comment: Did you verify that the .rc file is not opened in a source code editor?

Comment: No, definitely not currently open in any editor, either within VS or anywhere else.

Comment: If the displayed error says open in editor, resource.h is also include in that check. Make sure it is closed also.

Comment: Re-opened and closed all editor windows, still nothing under the .rc file in the resources tab.